# Kivy how to iterate through widgets/elements in layout?

Tags: python, kivy

If I have GridLayout and 60 widgets without IDs in it, can I somehow iterate through those wigets?

*For example: I need to unpress other 59 buttons, when I press particular one*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the parent widget (GridLayout in your case) from your kivy code using id. Now once you have it in python code with a variable name let's say `myGrid` then you can use `myGrid.children` to get all of it's children. You can iterate over them using a `for loop` like this:

```
for elements in myGrid.children:
    #do this
    #and this
```